# silverstripe external authentification

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

there is a custom login form that should give users access to certain contents on the same page. That works so far with Users stored as Members in the SS database and I was checking after Login if the user has permissions like this in the Page Class:

```
function isAllowed() {
    if (Member::currentUser()) {
        $PresseGroup = DataObject::get_one('Group', "Code = 'presse'");
        $AdminGroup = DataObject::get_one('Group', "Code = 'administrators'");
        if (Member::currentUser()->inGroup($PresseGroup->ID) || Member::currentUser()->inGroup($AdminGroup->ID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

in the Template I just did this:

```
<% if isAllowed %>  
SecretContent
<% end_if %>
```

OK so far, but now the users will not be stored in the silverstripe database - they are stored on a another server.

On that external server is running a little php script accepting the username and password. The script just returns user has permission: true or false.

I´m calling that script via cURL.

I planned to overwrite the dologin Function of MemberLoginForm. Now I just wonder how to check after Login that the User got the permission and display the contents... I tried to set a variable in the controller of the Page or should I set a session Variable? Thats my attempt (CustomLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm):

```
public function dologin($data) {
if(userHasPermission("user1", "pw")==true){
    $this->controller->Test("test");     
}
$link = $this->controller->Link();
$this->performLogin($data);
$this->controller->redirect($link);
}
```

I hope someone can help me with that - I know very specific - problem.
Many thanx,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

In SilverStripe you can create a custom authenticator, which means users can log in on your website with accounts that are stored somewhere else, or even just a hard coded user and password.
You can check out the [OpenID Authentication Module](https://github.com/oddnoc/silverstripe-auth_openid/) for example code on how to do it

But for your task this might even be to complex of a solution, how about after login just do something like `Session::set('isAllowed', true);` and to check if the user is allowed to view:

```
function isAllowed() {
    if (Member::currentUser()) {
        $PresseGroup = DataObject::get_one('Group', "Code = 'presse'");
        $AdminGroup = DataObject::get_one('Group', "Code = 'administrators'");
        if (Member::currentUser()->inGroup($PresseGroup->ID) || Member::currentUser()->inGroup($AdminGroup->ID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // if Member::currentUser() is not allowed to view, 
    // return the session, which is either set to true or it returns null if not set 
    return Session::get('isAllowed');
}
```